# Table row final cell wrongly sized

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to get both the table tow of the table one and table three to match in width- at present, the last cell does not. The reason for the two tables is fixed headers on table one and scrollable overflow content for table 2. This approach has worked in the past for me and I just cannot figure out what is different with this example to produce this error.

[image: Below is an image of how it appears on the page]

```css
#table_wrapper1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 47px;
  width: 500px;
}

#table1 {
  table-layout: fixed;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  border: solid 1px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

#table_wrapper2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 278px;
  left: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 150px;
}

#table2 {
  table-layout: fixed;
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  font-size: .7em;
  border: solid 1px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F7F7F7
}

td {
  padding: 4px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: #FFF4C6;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  padding: 6px;
  Border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: #BB8A76;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="table_wrapper1">
  <table class="table" id="table1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Unit code</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Delete unit</th>
        <th>Add new unit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>

  </table>
</div>

<div id="table_wrapper2">
  <table class="table" id="table2">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input class="unit <?php echo $class;?>" type="text" name="unit_code[]" value="<?php echo @$_POST['unit_code'][0]?>"></td>
        <td><textarea cols="10" rows="3" class="<?php echo $class;?>" name="unit_description[]"><?php echo @$_POST['unit_description'][0]?></textarea></td>
        <td><img title="remove unit" class="remove_row" src="../images/exit.png"> </td>
        <td><img title="add more units" class="add_row" src="../images/add-resource.png"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you get this to work before? The problem is that the scrollbar `overflow: scroll;` is adding a scrollbar to the right, which will obviously change the size of the columns in the table

Comment: You need 2 tables to get the "fixed header" when scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue might be the `overflow: scroll;`. Removing this seems to work on my end.

Edit: Unfortunately you're going to continue running into this issue with the `overflow: scroll` due to the scrollbar naturally taking up space. You could trying applying negative right padding to your table body wrapper, but you'll then run into browser compatibility issues. Perhaps you could try applying the `overflow: scroll` to the upper wrapper as well? It wouldn't be pretty, but it might work nonetheless.

Comment: But removing that breaks the functionality - the whole purpose of 2 tables was so that the 2nd one could be scrolled.

Comment: Unfortunately you're going to continue running into this issue with the `overflow: scroll` due to the scrollbar naturally taking up space. You could trying applying negative right padding to your table body wrapper, but you'll then run into browser compatibility issues.

Perhaps you could try applying the `overflow: scroll` to the upper wrapper as well? It wouldn't be pretty, but it might work nonetheless.

Comment: Its not my question (please check the poster/commenters name before addressing anyone), I was just pointing out why your answer doesn't fix the OP's issue. They claim to have got it working before, so I'm waiting on their answer so see how they managed to do it before.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I recognized your username and somehow mixed it up with the OP's.

Comment: It is very weird I have a table where this already works perfectly - both tables line up and there is just a vertical scroller when there are too many enteries